# GetPropertyValues not being called in Custom Profile Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to implement my first custom profile provider for my MVC3 application.

My profile model is -

```
    Public Class Profile
    Inherits ProfileBase

    Public Overridable Property FirstName As String
    Public Overridable Property LastName As String

    Public Overridable Property COUNTY_NUM As Integer
    Public Overridable Property COUNTY_ONLY_SW As String
    Public Overridable Property WORKER_TYPE_IND As String
    Public Overridable Property Agency As Decimal

    Public Shared Function GetProfile(userName As String) As Profile

        Return DirectCast(Create(userName), Profile)

    End Function

End Class
```

I've implemented a default Profile provider based on System.Web.Profile.ProfileProvider with all methods implemented and throwing exceptions and breakpoints on all the throws.  When I step through the GetProfile() method, it doesn't call any of the functions in the ProfileProvider.   I know that my profile provider does get called because if the web config doesn't load/find class, I get an error.

Am I missing step?